# Designing an efficient search by tag solution

Tags: database-design, sql

I've a project where the users will be able to tags themselves with **skills tags** (maybe predefined in the system) , and then the project managers on a company would be able to search the best user with a set of skills for a given task. For example : **Java** would be  a tag, or maybe **Android** , etc. I'll use a relational DB. I've so far the following options:

1. **Users**, **UserTags**, **Tags**  tables.
2. **Users** and **Tags** tables, storing each user's tags as an **user_tags** text column (in **Users**).

**N° 1** it's the most correct way to do it in terms of pure logic design , but at the time of searching it would require to query the three tables. More over, the  Project Manager can also search by user's name, so maybe a query could be :

```
SELECT users.name, users.id FROM users, user_tags, tags WHERE (tags.name={query} AND tags.id=user_tags.tag_id AND user.id=user_tags.id) OR users.name LIKE '%{query}%' LIMIT N .
```

I don't know  if it's an efficient query, notice I have an OR with a LIKE statement.

With option **N° 2** I'll have a storage penalty (storing many times the same TAG name for each user) , but maybe I could perform a FULLTEXT indexed search on the column **tags** and **name** of **User** , therefore querying only one table with a FULLTEXT index. Here the **Tags** table will be useful as a control table, validating if the selected tags by the user are permited.

So, what do you think it's the best approach?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are going to want to say that a project manager searching for 'c#' also gets '.net' but not 'c'

That means you'll want to group tags into categories, prevent 'C#' and 'c#' being different tags and be more clever with your search than just a word comparison.

You'll need more linked tables and want to refer to a tag by its id rather than its written english representation. So I would use the join table in this case.

(although I have a feeling that a relational db might not be the most scalable approach long term)

Comment: I've seen several related search DB questions and many of the answers suggested using a No-SQL solution, but why ? In terms of scalability , I thought in using a SQL cloud solution, but why do you say No-SQL is better for this ?

Comment: @gabdev I wouldn't go as far as to make a definite statement on the matter, but I would definitely put some work in to gage the scale of the eventual product. I have a feeling that a _good_ search will be computationally expensive and not a simple sql query